# cakephp3 clause where doesn't work

Tags: cakephp-3.0

the code below is executed but it brings a wrong records(all records in my table) , it's like he doesn't take on consideration the clause where

```
$result = $this->Posts->query('SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE id=1');
```

I know that I can do it easily with find() but for some reasons I want to write the sql statement and to have the right results
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend using Cake's ORM instead of raw queries: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html Edit: if you really want raw statements: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions

Comment: query() method just creates a query object, it does not take any parameter. If you want to execute a query follow sevvlor links

Comment: @sevvlor thank you for the solution

Comment: thanks  @arilia for the explanations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query() method does not take any parameter. you can use it like

```
$data= $this->Posts->query()
            ->where(['id'=>1])
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
```